# Unit testing sampling methods

Tags: hypothesis-testing, markov-chain-montecarlo, software, particle-filter

I'm writing a bit of code that makes pretty heavy use of sampling (eg, MCMC, Particle Filters, etc), and I would really like to test it to make sure that it's doing what I think it is before claiming any results.  Is there a typical way unit test these methods to ensure correctness?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the standard checks over the traces (correlation, whether it mixes well and so), for "unit testing" the sampling of each variable, for instance, in my Gibbs samplers, I do the following:

- Create a small toy dataset.
- In my Gibbs sampler, comment out (I use `if True` and `if False` statements) all variables but one, where the fixed variables (the ones not being sampled this time) are set to their true values.
- See whether the one sampled variable converges to its true value.

Do it with all the variables one by one. Then sampling two variables (try different pairs), and so, until I sample them all. Then I can use a more complicated toy dataset or just try over real data.

(still, I would love to see how other people do it and whether there is some "good practice" in terms of programming)

Comment: Another approach is a toy dataset with no data, so the loglikelihood is constant and the posterior should match the prior exactly.